# How tu use a variable in if in ftl?

Tags: freemarker

I am learning ftl and have problem with variables.
I have an element `a` which has its own subelement `b`.
I access the subelement with the following method:

```
a.getChild("b")
```

Now, I check whether a subelement has content in the following way:

```
<#if a.getChild("b").getData()?has_content>
```

and this works as expected.

Now, I wanted to shorten this `if`'s syntax by doing the following:

```
<#assign b>${a.getChild("b")}</#assign>
<#if b.getData()?has_content>
```

However, this produces error:

```
For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a string
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I eliminate the need for calling the `getChild` in `if`s?

I have hundreds of `if`s in my production environment which all use `getChild`, sometimes even multiple times if subelements are nested so it would be great if I could shorten the syntax by assigning a child element to a variable.

I just started learning ftl yesterday, so this might be stupid question, sorry.

Comment: Not related to the question itself, but note that `b.getData()` can be written as `b.data`. That's true for any other getter methods with 0 arguments too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do `<#assign b = a.getChild("b")>`.

With `${a.getChild("b")}` you've outputted a string which then was assigned.

See the documentation also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html

Comment: Or even `<#assign b = a.getChild("b").data>`, if OP will always just want the `data`.